# Override Plugin function

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins

I am using the WP Jobs Plugin with the add-on WP Jobs Application Deadline and there is a function that I need to change:

```
    public function display_the_deadline() {
    global $post;

    $deadline = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_application_deadline', true );
    $expiring = false;
    $expired  = false;
    $date_str = null;

    if ( $deadline ) {
        $expiring_days = apply_filters( 'job_manager_application_deadline_expiring_days', 2 );
        $expiring      = ( floor( ( current_time( 'timestamp' ) - strtotime( $deadline ) ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) >= -$expiring_days );
        $expired       = ( floor( ( current_time( 'timestamp' ) - strtotime( $deadline ) ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) >= 0 );
        $date_str      = date_i18n( $this->get_date_format(), strtotime( $deadline ) );
    }

    // Do not display anything if listing is already expired.
    if ( is_singular( 'job_listing' ) && $expired ) {
        return;
    }

    $timestamp = strtotime( $deadline );

    /**
     * Filters the display string for the application closing date.
     *
     * @since 1.2.1
     *
     * @param string $date_str  The default date string to be displayed.
     * @param string $timestamp The timestamp of the closing date.
     */
    $date_str = apply_filters( 'job_manager_application_deadline_closing_date_display', $date_str, $timestamp );

    if ( $date_str ) {
        echo '<li class="application-deadline ' . ( $expiring ? 'expiring' : '' ) . ' ' . ( $expired ? 'expired' : '' ) . '"><label>' . ( $expired ? __( 'Closed', 'wp-job-manager-application-deadline' ) : __( 'Closes', 'wp-job-manager-application-deadline' ) ) . ':</label> ' . $date_str . '</li>';
    }
}
```

In the section that echo's the "li class="application-deadline..." I need to change Closes: to Deadline: and am wondering if it is possible to override this function in my functions.php file. I tried to replace it using Jquery but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a great way to filter existing functions in plugins unless they're designed that way - and it doesn't appear this one is set up to allow that.

Using JavaScript should absolutely work. Since your HTML output is something like:

```
<li class="application-deadline expiring"><label>Closes:</label> Sept 4th, 2018</li>
```

You should be able to select the element fairly easily. Take a look at this vanilla JS snippet:

```js
let deadlines = document.querySelectorAll('.application-deadline');

for( i = 0, n = deadlines.length; i < n; ++i ){
  deadlines[i].innerText = deadlines[i].innerText.replace('Closes:', 'Deadline:');
}
```

```html
<li class="application-deadline expiring"><label>Closes:</label> Sept 4th, 2018</li>
```

Or if you so-desire, a jQuery version:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.application-deadline').each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace('Closes:', 'Deadline:') );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="application-deadline expiring"><label>Closes:</label> Sept 4th, 2018</li>
```

**Edit:** It appears your content is loaded in dynamically with Ajax. You could attempt to use [$.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) to handle the code:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete( function( event, request, settings){
  $('.application-deadline').each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace('Closes:', 'Deadline:') );
  });
});
```

Alternatively you can abuse CSS pseudo-elements to manipulate the text:

```
.job_listing-location.job-end label {
    font-size: 0;
}

.job_listing-location.job-end label:before {
    content: "Deadline:";
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the JavaScript/Jquery is not working. I think because the line I need to change doesn't exist yet when the function runs. I even tried it on page load but no luck :(

Comment: So the custom post type content is loaded in dynamically after the page is loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm just guessing because the js isn't working??

Comment: Are you sure your JavaScript is enqueued properly? Are you getting any errors in your Console? Can you share a link to the site in question?

Comment: The listings are loaded in with an Ajax request - I've edited my answer. You'll either need to handle it on the `ajaxComplete` or `ajaxSuccess` events, or you could just kind of "bypass" the whole issue and use CSS to hide the current label, and use the `:before` pseudo element to insert a the new one

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the $.ajaxComplete method and it works perfectly!